# Remove duplicate values from an array of objects in reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, duplicates, mapping

I have an array like so:

```js
reportData = [
    {status: "Resolved", type: Placement of bins},
    {status: "Assigned", type: Placement of bins},
    {status: "Active", type: Sewerage}
]
```

Now this is what I am trying to do. I want to make as many checkboxes as the count of reportData array but also remove the duplicated values, like in this case, I want "Placement of bins" only once (one checkbox). So overall according to the array there should be only 2 checboxes, but I'm getting three because obviously there are 3 objects in the array.

```
{
    reportData.map((obj) => {
        return (
            <FormControlLabel
                value="type"
                control={<Checkbox color="primary" />}
                label={obj.type}
                labelPlacement="end"
            />

        )
    })
}
```

Is there some way to first sort out the duplicated array of objects and maybe then I can map it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do,

```js
const mapped = reportData.map((obj, index) => obj.type);
const filtered = mapped.filter((type, index) =>  mapped.indexOf(type) === index  )
```

Here is what happened, `map` function made a new array called `mapped` that has the all types you had in `reportData` including duplicates.

`filter` filtered the duplicates as; `array.indexOf(element)` returns index of the first element that matches. Here, `'Placement of bins'` is in `0` and `1` indexes. So the iterations be like `true false true` since in first iteration it is `0 === 0`, in second: it's `0 === 1` and in third it's `2===2`. So filtered array only gets the elements of index `0` and `2`

And then using the filtered array to map to get checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks, it works prefectly. But can u please tell me what's happening in the second line?

Answer (score 1):

You could use lodash method _.uniqBy, it is available in the current version of lodash 4.17.2.

Example:

```
_.uniqBy([{status:"Resolved", type:'Placement of bins'},
             {status:"Assigned", type:'Placement of bins'},
             {status:"Active", type:'Sewerage'}], 'type');
// => [{status: "Resolved", type: "Placement of bins"}, {status: "Active", type: "Sewerage"}]
```

More info: https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy